Is there a way to load images in tkinter faster?
I am trying to implement images into buttons in tkinter, and when i try to load it, it takes more than 5 seconds for the images and window to load.
I want it so that when next button is clicked, the images load almost instantly so that i can debug and test the code faster (without wasting 6 seconds everytime).
Is there a better way (or faster) to load these images?
from tkinter import *
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import time
root = Tk()

# Tkinter stuff 
root.title("Projectile motion")
root.geometry("800x500")
root.resizable(False, False)
scale_label = None

def switch():
    page1.grid_forget()  # Hide the welcome page
    page2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")  # Show the instructions page
page1 = Frame(root, width=800, height=500)
page2 = Frame(root, width=800, height=500, bg = "azure3")


page1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
page2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

# main page stuff
main_window_title = Label(page1, text="Projectile Motion Simulation", font=("Times New Roman bold", 35))
main_window_title.place(relx=0.13, rely=0.26)

main_window_button = Button(page1, text="Start", font=("Arial bold", 15), background= "#ff0000", activebackground= "#f08080", command=switch,
                            height=4, width=20)
main_window_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor="center")

# page 2/ instructions page
welcome_text = Label(page2, text="Welcome to Projectile Motion simulation",bg = "azure3", font=("Times New Roman bold", 30))
welcome_text.place(relx = 0,rely = 0)

htp_text = Label(page2, text="How to play?", bg = "azure3" ,font=("Times New Roman", 25))
htp_text.place(relx = 0, rely = 0.1)

instruction_text = ("1) Use sliders, checkboxes, and buttons to adjust the simulation\n" 
                    "2) Press 'Launch' button to show output values\n" 
                    "3) Press checkboxes to show values on animation window\n"
                    "4) Press 'projectile 1' and 'projectile 2' to switch between projectiles \n"
                    "5) Press 'Explanation' button to get the theory on projectile motion\n"
                    "6) Press 'Quiz' button to try a quiz on projectile motion\n"
                    "7) Press back button to close window")


htp2_text = Label(page2, text=instruction_text,font=("Times New Roman", 20),  bg = "azure3",justify='left', anchor='w')
htp2_text.place(relx = 0,rely = 0.2)


def selection_window():      
    selection_window = Toplevel()
    selection_window.title("Selection page")
    selection_window.config(width=500, height=500)
    selection_window.resizable(False, False)
    selection_window.bind("<Destroy>", enable_button)

    click_btn= PhotoImage(file="scenario 1.png")
    click_btn = click_btn.zoom(25)
    click_btn = click_btn.subsample(40)
    
    click_btn2= PhotoImage(file="scenario 2.png")
    click_btn2 = click_btn2.zoom(25) 
    click_btn2 = click_btn2.subsample(40)
    
    global button1
    button1 = Button(selection_window, image = click_btn,command=vertical_animation)
    button1.image = click_btn
    button1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    global button2
    button2 = Button(selection_window,image = click_btn2 ,command=lambda: animation_window(1))
    button2.image = click_btn2
    button2.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
    root.withdraw()

when next button is clicked, it loads for around 6 seconds]

I have changed my code from PhotoImage to Image.open. I tried it on a separate file and it works perfectly fine. But when i copy it to my code it doesn't seem to work.
this is the code in the separate file
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Image Buttons")
# Load images
scenario1_img = Image.open("scenario 1.png")
scenario1_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(scenario1_img)
scenario2_img = Image.open("scenario 2.png")
scenario2_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(scenario2_img)

# Create buttons with images
button1 = tk.Button(root, image=scenario1_img, command=lambda: button_clicked(1))
button2 = tk.Button(root,image=scenario2_img , command=lambda: button_clicked(2))

# Display buttons
button1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
button2.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()

then this is my code.
def enable_button(event=None):
    global next_button
    next_button["state"] = "normal"
    if 'button2' in globals() and button2.winfo_exists():
        button2["state"] = "normal"
    if 'button1' in globals() and button1.winfo_exists():
        button1["state"] = "normal"

def selection_window():
    next_button["state"] = "disabled"

    
    selection_window = Toplevel()
    selection_window.title("Selection page")
    selection_window.config(width=500, height=500)
    selection_window.resizable(False, False)
    selection_window.bind("<Destroy>", enable_button)

    scenario1_img = Image.open("scenario 1.png")
    scenario1_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(scenario1_img)
    
    scenario2_img = Image.open("scenario 2.png")
    scenario2_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(scenario2_img)   
    
    global button1
    
    button1= Button(selection_window, image=scenario1_img,command=vertical_animation)
    button1.grid(row=0, column=0,padx=10, pady=10)

    global button2
    
    button2= Button(selection_window,image=scenario2_img,command=lambda: animation_window(1))
    button2.grid(row=0, column=1,padx=10, pady=10)
    
    root.withdraw()

This is the result

I am not sure if it has anything to do with the enable_button() function, but when i close the window this error shows up.


The time taken is mostly on zoom() and subsample().  Why don't you use Pillow.Image to resize the images?

Or simply resize the images outside of the program, so that you can load them directly without further processing.

I just tried adding Image.open instead of Photoimage. I tested the code on one file and it worked perfectly fine, after copying it to my code it doesnt work.
I will edit my post and show the problem.

It is better to provide a [mre] for your updated code as currently we cannot execute the updated code.

Missing root.mainloop()

I just found a solution to it. I just had to global scenario1_img and scenario2_img

Unfortunately hasn't way to do that. Creating a tkimage takes much time. And if you have a gif with hundreds of frames...


But here are some things you maybe can considerate:

Think a litle, if the images and configurations will always be the same , you do not need to recreate then every time.
Load all images at beginning of script. So the waiting time will be at "initialization" not at "runtime".
Use images with the proper size to avoid using .zoom() and .subsample(). Less work, more speed.
In specific cases you can put all images in a generator, so it will be created only when called:

    tkimages = (tk.PhotoImage(file=img) for img in list_images_png)
    button.configure(image=next(tkimages))

